Unable to connect to Postgres 17 on Ubuntu 24.04 localhost
I'm trying to login to psql using sudo -u postgres psql from terminal on local machine but the default password like postgres is not working. Also, I noticed the default port is now 5433 instead of old 5432 in previous versions. Please let me know the password if you happen to know the same.
Connection attempts from clients like DBeaver also failed due to the same issue.
xander@workstation:/usr/lib/postgresql/17$ sudo -u postgres psql
Password for user postgres: 
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Extract from postgresql.conf:
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = 'localhost'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5433             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100

Extract from pg_hba.conf:
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256

TIA!

What version of Ubuntu are you running? Where did you get postgresql-17?  Port 5433 is usually assigned at install time when there is already a running postgresql on port 5432, so you can run both simultaneously. Please add requested information to your original posting.

@ubfan1 Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is already mentioned in the title. I think there was a prompt while running upgrade to upgrade Postgres to version 17. There's no other services listening to port 5432. Currently, there's only one instance of postgres running on port 5433.

Postgresql 17 was released Sept. 26, 2024, so it is not in the Ubuntu 24.04 nor 24.10 beta  standard repositories.

I ended up purging everything and then reinstalling Postgres 16.

You may answer your own question, and after a bit, accept it, helping others and gaining some reputation points in the process.

I followed the below official tutorials to completely uninstall Postgresql and then did a clean reinstall of Postgresql 16.
Uninstall Postgresql:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/uninstall-postgresql-ubuntu/
Install Postgressql:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-getting-started/install-postgresql-linux/
Please don't forget to uncomment the following in postgresql.conf
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = 'localhost'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5433             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100

If you wish enable remote connections then you may either set listen_addresses="*" or better include specific IP addresses from where the connection is originating. Latter option is recommended for better security.
Hope this helps!
